# Normalization for solving linear equations

Tags: linear, matrix-inverse

Suppose I want to solve a linear equation system in the form of 
$$A x = b$$
to get $x$, where $A$ are $n$ by $n$ matrix and $b$ is $n$ by 1 vector. Is there any normalization procedure necessary before passing the value to solver? Here "normalization" means two things for me:

1. If all elements of $A$ and $b$ are at the magnitude of $1 \times 10^{10}$, it is necessary to divide both sides by $1 \times 10^{10}$? I know from theoretical point of view this wouldn't matter, but not sure if matters numerically.
2. The equation is not solvable when the matrix is singular, i.e. $det(A) = 0$. In real life, $det(A)$ is never exactly zero, so we can only say whether $det(A) < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a small threshold. However, $det(A)$ can be made arbitrarily small by dividing a large number on both sides of the equation. Therefore, I guess the criterion should be something like $det(A) / det(b) < \epsilon$ but there is no determinant operator for vector $b$. What should be the correct normalization for $det(A)$ here?

Comment: Standard solvers automatically take care of these issues, so it's not anything you need to worry about unless $A$ is ill-conditioned.  That's determined by its condition number, not the (absolute value of) its determinant.

Comment: @whuber thanks, I think condition number is exactly the metric I'm looking for

Comment: @whuber I see a vote to close this as needing details or clarity but it seems to me you have answered it and the OP has accepted your answer, albeit in comments. So, I am leaving it open but maybe your comment is an answer?